# Dynamic nested menu in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this object:

```
[
 {
    id: 1,
    child: false,
    link_type: expand
 },
 {
    id: 2,
    child: true,
    url: /home,
    link_type: direct,
    parent: 1
 },
 {
    id: 3,
    child: false,
    url: /settings,
    link_type: direct
 }
]
```

I want to do nesting of the object in such a way that the final output will be:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    link_type: expand,
    child: [
        {
            id: 2,
            url: /home,
           link_type: direct,
           parent: 1
        }
      ]
 },
 {
   id: 3,
   url: /settings,
   link_type: direct
 }
]
```

note: the orignal data has other fields I have included fields that are needed.

**I have tried creating a nesting like this for parent node:**

```
this.sideMenuService.getAll().subscribe(d => {
         console.log(JSON.stringify(d));
         let data: SideMenuList = {};
         let count = 0;
         d.forEach(e => {
            if (!e.child) {
               // console.log(count);
               // console.log(e.menu_id);
               data.menu_id = e.menu_id;
               data.displayname = e.displayname;
               data.iconcss = e.iconcss;
               data.link_type = e.link_type;
               data.sequence = e.sequence;
               data.url = e.url;
               console.log(data);
               this.sideMenuList.push(data);
               // console.log(this.sideMenuList);
               count++;
            }
         });
         console.log(this.sideMenuList);
});
```

But i am getting output like this:
[image: output]

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to iterate over the data and create a new nested array as followings.

But your data is invalid. Please note the quotation marks added to the data

```js
const data = [{
    id: 1,
    child: false,
    link_type: "expand"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    child: true,
    url: "/home",
    link_type: "direct",
    parent: 1
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    child: false,
    url: "/settings",
    link_type: "direct"
  },
  // This one is added to show multi-level nest
  {
    id: 4,
    child: true,
    url: "/settings",
    link_type: "direct",
    parent: 2
  }
]

const denormalized = data.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  if (!cur.parent) {
    acc.push(cur)
  }
  const children = data.filter(child => child.parent === cur.id)
  if (children.length > 0) {
    cur.children = children
  }
  return acc;

}, [])

console.log(denormalized)
```

Comment: Can you help with the source where I can find stuff like this ? Thanks in advance.